# Im having trouble figuring out why my paddles and ball images wont show up on pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pong

## starting all modules and window

```
        import pygame, sys, time, random from pygame.locals import *

        pygame.init()
        bg = pygame.image.load("./soccerfield.png")

        mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

        WINDOWWIDTH = 800
        WINDOWHEIGHT = 600
        SIZESIDES = 20
        MIDDLESIZE = 10
        FPS = 30
        PADDLESPEED = 10


        #Rects of the board of the game
        TOPSIDE = pygame.Rect(0, 0, WINDOWWIDTH, SIZESIDES)
        BOTTOMSIDE = pygame.Rect(0, WINDOWHEIGHT - SIZESIDES, WINDOWWIDTH, SIZESIDES)
        MIDDLE = []
        for i in range(0, 31):
            MIDDLE.append(pygame.Rect(WINDOWWIDTH/2 - MIDDLESIZE/2,15 + i*20, MIDDLESIZE, MIDDLESIZE))    

        windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)

        pygame.display.set_caption('Running_window')
        "defining colors"
        BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
        WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

        gameIsPlaying = False
```

## These are used to print the scores

```
        CHIFFRES =[
        '''WWWWW
        W   W
        W   W
        W   W
        WWWWW''',
        '''    W
            W
            W
            W
            W''',
        '''WWWWW
            W
        WWWWW
        W    
        WWWWW''',
        '''WWWWW
            W
        WWWWW
            W
        WWWWW''',
        '''W   W
        W   W
        WWWWW
            W
            W''',
        '''WWWWW
        W    
        WWWWW
            W
        WWWWW''',
        '''WWWWW
        W    
        WWWWW
        W   W
        WWWWW''',
        '''WWWWW
            W
          WWW
            W
            W''',
        '''WWWWW
        W   W
        WWWWW
        W   W
        WWWWW''',
        '''WWWWW
        W   W
        WWWWW
            W
        WWWWW''',
        '''''']

        #Functions

            #Draw the score (in fact return a list with the rect to draw, drawn later with drawGame())
        def drawChiffre(a, x, y):
            countx = 0
            county = 0
            rectList = []
            for piece in CHIFFRES[a]:
                if countx % 7 == 5 or countx % 7 == 6:
                    countx +=1
                    county +=0.5
                if piece == '''W''':
                    rectList.append(pygame.Rect(x + (countx%7)*10, y + county*15, MIDDLESIZE, MIDDLESIZE*1.5))
                    countx +=1
                elif piece == ''' ''':
                    countx +=1
            return rectList

            #Doesn't work, meant to change the score in case of a win from either side
        def score(ball, scoreP1, scoreP2):
            if ball.l <= 0:
                scoreP1 +=1
                ball = Ball(WINDOWHEIGHT/2, WINDOWWIDTH/2, 15, 15, 5, 5)
            if ball.l >= WINDOWWIDTH:
                scoreP2 +=1
                ball = Ball(WINDOWHEIGHT/2, WINDOWWIDTH/2, 15, 15, 5, 5)

 function that draws everything in game =============================================

        def drawGame(Paddle1, scoreP1, Paddle2, scoreP2, Ball):
            windowSurface.fill(BLACK)
            windowSurface.blit(bg,(0,0))

        Paddle1.draw()
        Paddle1.pygame.image.load("./soccerplayer1")
        windowSurface.blit(Paddle1)
        Paddle2.draw()
        Paddle2.pygame.image.load("./soccerplayer2")
        windowSurface.blit(Paddle2)
        Ball.draw()
        Ball = pygame.image.load("./soccerball.png")
        windowSurface.blit(Ball)

            drawScoreP2 = drawChiffre(scoreP2, 450, 50)
            for piece in drawScoreP2:
                pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, WHITE, piece)

            drawScoreP1 = drawChiffre(scoreP1, 300, 50)
            for piece in drawScoreP1:
                pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, WHITE, piece)

            pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, WHITE, TOPSIDE) 
            pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, WHITE, BOTTOMSIDE)

            for piece in MIDDLE :
                pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, WHITE, piece)



            #A function for writing a text with the most basic font
        def write(text, fontSize, x, y):
            font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, fontSize)

            textR = font.render(text, True, WHITE, None)
            textRect = textR.get_rect()
            textRect.centerx = x
            textRect.centery = y
            windowSurface.blit(textR, textRect)

        #Classes

            #The paddles
        class Paddle:
            rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 0, 0)
            movement = 0

            def __init__(self, l, t, w, h):
                self.l = l
                self.t = t
                self.w = w
                self.h = h
            def setRect(self):
                self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.l, self.t, self.w, self.h)
            def setPosition(self):
                self.position = self.t
            def setMovement(self, x):
                self.movement = x
            def move(self):
                self.t = self.t + self.movement*PADDLESPEED
                self.setPosition()
                self.setRect()
            def draw(self):
                pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, WHITE, self.rect)
            def collideWithSide(self, upSide, downSide):
                if (self.t + self.h) > downSide:
                    self.setMovement(0)
                if (self.t) < upSide:
                    self.setMovement(0)

            #The ball
        class Ball:
            rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 0, 0)
            position = [0, 0]

            def __init__(self, l, t, w, h, x, y):
                self.speed = [x, y]
                self.l = l
                self.t = t
                self.w = w
                self.h = h
            def setRect(self):
                self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.l, self.t, self.w, self.h)
            def setPosition(self):
                self.position = [self.l, self.t]
            def setSpeed(self, x, y):
                self.speed = [x, y]
            def draw(self):
                pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, WHITE, self.rect)
            def move(self):
                self.l = self.l + self.speed[0]
                self.t = self.t + self.speed[1]
                self.setRect()
                self.setPosition()
            def bounce(self, paddle):
                if self.rect.colliderect(paddle.rect):
                    self.setSpeed(-self.speed[0], self.speed[1])
            def collideWithSide(self, upSide, downSide):
                if (self.t + self.h) > downSide or (self.t) < upSide:
                    self.setSpeed(self.speed[0], -self.speed[1])
```

### Now the core of the game

while True:

```
            #Initialization of the score and of the paddles and ball
            scoreP1 = 0
            scoreP2 = 0

            paddle1 = Paddle(0, WINDOWHEIGHT/2 - 40, 15, 80)
            paddle2 = Paddle(WINDOWWIDTH - 15, WINDOWHEIGHT/2 - 40, 15, 80)
            ball = Ball(WINDOWWIDTH/2, WINDOWHEIGHT/2, 15, 15, 5, 5)
        start
```

## "menu"

```
            while not gameIsPlaying:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == QUIT:
                            pygame.quit()
                            sys.exit()
                        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                            if event.key == ord('s'):
                                gameIsPlaying = True
                        if event.type == KEYUP:
                            if event.key == ord('q'):
                                pygame.quit()
                                sys.exit()


                drawGame(paddle1, scoreP1, paddle2, scoreP2, ball)

                write('Press s', 120, WINDOWWIDTH/4, WINDOWHEIGHT/2)
                write('to play!', 120, 3*WINDOWWIDTH/4, WINDOWHEIGHT/2)

                write('Press q', 60, 3*WINDOWWIDTH/8, 3*WINDOWHEIGHT/4)
                write('to quit.', 60, 5*WINDOWWIDTH/8, 3*WINDOWHEIGHT/4)

                write('e', 60 , 20, WINDOWHEIGHT/4)
                write('d', 60, 20, 3*WINDOWHEIGHT/4)

                write('UP', 30, WINDOWWIDTH - 15, WINDOWHEIGHT/4)
                write('DOWN', 30, WINDOWWIDTH -30, 3*WINDOWHEIGHT/4)

                pygame.display.update()
                mainClock.tick(FPS)

            #This is the game playing
            while gameIsPlaying:
```

## what keys are used to control paddles and the direction they move

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == QUIT:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
                    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == K_ESCAPE or event.key == ord('a'):
                            gameIsPlaying = False
                        if event.key == ord('e'):
                            paddle1.setMovement(-1)
                        if event.key == ord('d'):
                            paddle1.setMovement(1)
                        if event.key == K_UP:
                            paddle2.setMovement(-1)
                        if event.key == K_DOWN:
                            paddle2.setMovement(1)
                    if event.type == KEYUP:
                        if event.key == ord('e'):
                            paddle1.setMovement(0)
                        if event.key == ord('d'):
                            paddle1.setMovement(0)
                        if event.key == K_UP:
                            paddle2.setMovement(0)
                        if event.key == K_DOWN:
                            paddle2.setMovement(0)


                #Move the ball and the paddles
                paddle1.move()
                paddle2.move()
                ball.move()

                #Collision between the ball and the paddles
                ball.bounce(paddle1)
                ball.bounce(paddle2)
```

### Check if score and incrementation

```
                if ball.l <= 0:
                    scoreP1 +=1
                    ball = Ball(WINDOWWIDTH/2, WINDOWHEIGHT/2, 15, 15, random.randint(3, 5), random.randint(3, 5))
                if ball.l >= WINDOWWIDTH:
                    scoreP2 +=1
                    ball = Ball(WINDOWWIDTH/2, WINDOWHEIGHT/2, 15, 15, random.randint(3, 5), random.randint(3, 5))

                #Check if winner and displaying and back to the menu
                if scoreP1 >= 10:
                    write('WINNER', 60, WINDOWWIDTH/8, 2*WINDOWHEIGHT/8)
                    pygame.display.update()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    gameIsPlaying = False

                if scoreP2 >= 10:
                    write('WINNER', 60, 5*WINDOWWIDTH/8, 2*WINDOWHEIGHT/8)
                    pygame.display.update()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    gameIsPlaying = False

                #Collision of the paddles and the ball with the sides
                paddle1.collideWithSide(20, 580)
                paddle2.collideWithSide(20, 580)
                ball.collideWithSide(20, 580)


                drawGame(paddle1, scoreP1, paddle2, scoreP2, ball)

                #Acceleration of the ball
                ball.setSpeed(ball.speed[0]*1.001, ball.speed[1])

                write('Press escape close game', 15, WINDOWWIDTH/8, WINDOWHEIGHT-SIZESIDES*2)

                pygame.display.update()
                mainClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you loading the images in this code here:

```
Paddle1.draw()
Paddle1.pygame.image.load("./soccerplayer1")
windowSurface.blit(Paddle1)
```

You should set the paddle image during class instantiation.  Also you are trying to blit the class not the image, hence why it isn't showing up.  Your Paddle class should be like this (this assumes Paddle1 is the object and not the class name):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.myimage = pygame.image.load("./soccerplayer1")
    ....
```

and then you can draw it like this:

```
windowSurface.blit(Paddle1.myimage, (x,y))
```

Maybe edit the post to add the classes? and it would help.